# Recognizing different sections in a config file using lex

Tags: regex, parsing, bison, yacc, lex

I have a configuration file as follows.

```
    e_type=0x1B                                                                                                                                                                           
    HID=0xaabbccddeeff
```

I use the following lex file to recognize the pattern.

```
%option noyywrap
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum{
    T_E_TYPE = 1,                                                                                                                                                                         
    T_HID_TYPE = 2,
};
int yylval;

%}

%%
%{
yylval = 0; /* do this for every token not using yylval, to be on the safe side */
%}
e_type=0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+        { yylval=strtoul(&yytext[9],NULL, 16); return T_E_TYPE; }
HID=0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+           { return T_HID_TYPE; }
[^\t\n\r]                       {   }   
%%

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    int tok = 0;
    if(argc > 1)
    {   
        FILE *file;
        file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        if(!file)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s \n", argv[1]);
            exit(1);
        }
        yyin = file;
    }   
    while((tok = yylex()) != 0)
    {   
        printf("token :%d lval : %d yytext : %s\n",tok,yylval,yytext);
    }   
}
```

I compile the program as follows

```
 flex test.l ; gcc lex.yy.c -o test
```

I run the program.

```
./test tmp.conf
```

Output:

```
token :1 lval : 27 yytext : e_type=0x1B

token :2 lval : 0 yytext : HID=0xaabbccddeeff
```

So far so good. If I extend my input file as follows

```
 [section1]
    e_type=0x1B                                                                                                                                                                           
    HID=0xaabbccddeeff
 [section2]
    e_type=0x1B                                                                                                                                                                           
    HID=0xaabbccddeeff
```

Is there a way to recognize which section each token belongs to using lex.? Or do I need to use yacc/bison for that.?

Comment: You don't need to use bison. But you may well find it easier, if you take the time to learn how it works. (By "easier", here, I mean that the resulting code is simpler, which means the learning part might be a good investment.) If you just use flex, the end result will look a lot like an `awk` program.

Comment: @rici - how do I do that using just flex ?

Comment: As I said, the same way you'd do it in [awk](http://passingcuriosity.com/2010/updating-an-ini-file-with-awk/)

Comment: @rici - I see.thanks

Comment: I'm not saying that's a good idea. But it's certainly *possible*. My recommendation is to learn bison.

Comment: @rici - Ok.Is it easy to do it using bison ?

Comment: Sure. You'd use a grammar roughly like: `file: | file section; section: HEADER | section assignment; assignment: ID '=' VALUE;`; in the `section` actions you'd create a map of id to value, and in the file action you'd add the section map to a global map.

Comment: @rici - I am trying to understand it.A bit more explenation would be helpful :)

Comment: The manual starts with a tutorial: https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Concepts.html#Concepts I did use the words "learn" and "investment", right? :) My comment was just a teaser, really.

Comment: @thanks :) appreciate it